# vsphere HA - VM Monitoring doesn't work

Tags: vmware, high-availability, vsphere, heartbeat, vmware-tools

I am looking for the VM Monitoring functionality in vsphere 6.0, I have followed some instruction found, but after all required steps to enable this functionality I don't know why I don't see the expected behavior:

1. "On" vSphere HA
2. Installed VMWare tools on guest environment
3. start VM
4. /etc/init.d/vmware-tools I have stopped the service <- so from now no Heartbeats are sent to Host machine

BUT Nothing happened.. What I expected here was a restart of VM.
What am I wronging?
Even If VM Monitoring is based also on  VM's disk/network I/O I have used fork bomb, but nothing happened..
Below my configuration
[image]

[image]
Tks guys
Prisco

Answer (score 0):

I think FORK bomb will increase the computation not the freeze the Disk I/O or network drops.Try to stop the disk I/O and network I/O in the VM level.Hope that will be restart your machine.The VMware has build an intelligence to avoid the false restart trigger.

Refer Duncan's Blog more about the VM monitoring.
http://ha.yellow-bricks.com/vm_and_application_monitoring.html